# How many hexagons to fill a square tile

Tags: tiling, mixed-integer-programming

I am filling a square tile of width wTile with equal hexagons stacked flat side on top of each other at an angle I call colourAngle as shown in the diagram. I call the rows of hexagons "Perp Line" which go from 0 to n. For clarity, I have not filled in all the hexagons in the diagram.

If I want to completely fill the square tile with hexagons and I am given a required colourAngle A and a hexagon density d, then

1. How many Perp Lines do I need and
2. How many hexagons are needed
3. What is the radius of the hexagons, rHex.

In the example shown there are 18 Perp Lines (including 0)

I have been having much more trouble than I expected trying to work this out.

**Thoughts so far:** The hexagon density (see diagram for equation) is dependent on the size of the hexagons, i.e. rHex.

The number of perp lines is also dependent on the density.

The density is the area of the square tile divided by the area of a single hexagon.

Perhaps the problem would be easier if the hexagons were decomposed into 6 equilateral triangles.

[image: Hexagons filling a square tile]

Comment: Can you find the equation of the line for for the general perp line $p$?

Comment: No. Only after I find rHex which is determined by the number of perp lines.

Comment: 1/ Indeed, write it in terms of $rHex$ (since clearly the perp line n does depend on rHex). 2/ You might need to add more details, like what hexagon density has to do with the problem.

Comment: @CalvinLin I edited the question to say that the number of perp lines and rHex depend on the hexagon density.

Comment: Can you clarify what is Hexagon Density? How does it affect Perp line 1?

Comment: Hexagon Density is the number of hexagons per unit area of the square tiles. The formula is given in the diagram d = nHexX . nHexY / wTile^2

Comment: This raises even more questions. EG define nHexX and nHex Y then. And keep on going all the way till everything has been clarified.  EG Is the placement of the tiles up to the individual? Could a density of 0.5 lead to different results?

Comment: nHexX and nHexY are shown in the diagram, i.e. the number of hexagons on the edge in the X direction and the number in the Y direction. The square tile is completely covered by hexagons. Any placement which achieves that satisfies the conditions. And yes, the size of the hexagons will be completely changed if the density is changed. e.g. if the density is 1 hexagon/unit area, rHex will be approximately double what it would be if the density was 4 hexagons per unit area.

Comment: FWIW I read nHex X as the width, not as the number of tiles, because you didn't define it clearly. Unfortunately, we are not mind readers. $\quad$ FWIW Let rHex = r, and find formulas for d, perp line p, and then solve then solve for perp line n > (top right corner). IE Start writing equations down.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, because the hexagons are not square, nHexX and nHexY don't make sense. The density is the number of hexagons per unit area but that is not nHexX.nHexY.

Comment: You can keep it in terms of area, IE You want "area of square / area of hexagon". $\quad$ This just depends on rHex, so use that as the subject-variable (since it's easier to condition other equations on rHex, rather than on d).